# using vba to count buttonclicks on a userform

Tags: vba, counter

Need help using vba to count button clicks. any suggestions???

```
  couner = counter+1
```

this is what i found.

"The form does not necessarily have to have any link to the Audit Table, use a recordset to update the counter value. Use the DLookup function to find out the value in the Table ie

DLookup "[Counter]","Audit"

A progression from this would be to have an AuditTable with [Autonumber] and [ButtonName]. In this way you could count several ButtonClicks but give each button in your Db a separate name so to count these

DCount "[AutoNumber","AuditTable","[ButtonName] = 'NameOfButtonToCount'" You can then put this alongside the button in a visible or hidden field."

---

Actually this is for an excel doc. I have to submit a spreadsheet for pc printer mapping to another group to process. the purpose of counting clicks is to help tell the program to go to the next row in excel. I add anywhere between 1-15 pcs to one spreadsheet and just trying to automate the process.

Comment: You might want to explain in more detail what you need to do: "count button clicks" is not very expansive.  We could guess you want to do this in Access - if that's the case then it would be good to specify that.  Also there's a problem with youe code sample ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Going to assume you want some sort of audit log for actions taken using buttons on an Access form.  Without knowing anything else all I can do is try to point you in the right direction.  If you're trying to see who is doing what and when in your database then you can create an AuditTable with fields: Form, Button, Timestamp, User, Computer.  Whenever the user clicks a button, executes a SQL statement to update the audit table:

```
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "INSERT INTO " & _
    "AuditTable " & _
        "(Form, Button, Timestamp, User, Computer)" & _
    "VALUES" & _
        "('" & Me.Name & "','" & YOUR_BUTTON_NAME_HERE & "',#" & Now & "#, '" & Environ$("username") & "','" & Environ$("computername") & "');"

CurrentDb.Execute SQL
```

If you want to count your button clicks you can then: `SELECT Button, count(1) as Clicks FROM AuditTable GROUP BY Button`